# append a microsoft access table to an excel doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So I saw the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849580/export-ms-access-tables-through-vba-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-same-directory), about exporting access to excel. The answer was perfect, however I could not comment to add a follow up question as follows.

Is it possible to append an access table to the end of an excel spreadsheet? If so how.

Comment: Have you tried `Data>>From Access` in Excel ?

Comment: im looking for a way to do it out of access. i have a lot of data that i need in excel for the people consuming it, split into several workbooks, id rather not have to go into every excel book manually to update it

Comment: You can use automation to open your excel files and place the data.

Comment: darn, i was hoping there would be an easy way to do it, similar to the method in the link in the original post, thanks for your help!

Comment: This link which is posted as an answer in your linked question shows how to automate Excel from Access to do what you want: http://access.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0035.htm