# Excel Memory Management: What does closing Excel do?

Tags: excel, vba, memory-management

I'm getting some "Out of Memory" errors when running my macro. My macro setup can be split up into two parts:
1) open an Excel file and run a bunch of its macros
2) open another Excel file that is pretty big (800 MB) and extract data

-- Part #1 of the macro completes just fine. When Part #2 starts, there is a hang up when it tries to open the Excel file.

-- I've figured one workaround is to save the workbook after Part #1 finishes, close workbook, re-open the workbook, and then run macro Part #2.

-- I've read that maybe saving the workbook could free up some memory. So I added code to save after Part #1 ends and before starting Part #2, but that didn't help.

**Is there anyway I can use VBA to free up the same amount of memory as if I closed and re-opened Excel? Or is there at least other methods to free up memory besides emptying variables?**

I've attached a picture of the Locals window to show what is still stored in memory after Part #1 finishes -- which is right before I get "Out of Memory" error. The thing I don't get it is that my workaround (i.e., close and re-open workbook to run Part #2) still creates all the **non-empty** variables you see in the Locals screenshot before running Part #2. So I can't free  up any more memory by setting variables to `Nothing`.

[image]

Here is the meat of my macro:

```
Sub main_macro()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim reg_wb, thisfile, sc_wb As Workbook

Set thisfile = ThisWorkbook

GageSht.Select
gage_factors = Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Value
config_list = Range("H3", Range("H3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Value
regime_sub_list = Range("O3", Range("O3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Value

InputSht.Select
gage_tape_run = sort_rng_arr(Range("gage_list").Row, Range("gage_list").Column, Range("gage_list").End(xlToRight).Column)

If UBound(gage_tape_run) > 1 Then
    unique_gage_list = remove_dupes_array(Application.Index(gage_tape_run, 0, 1))
Else
    Dim single_gage(1 To 1) As Variant
    single_gage(1) = Range("gage_list")
    unique_gage_list = single_gage
End If

WOWsht.Visible = True
WOWsht.Select
If Range("A3") <> "" Then
    Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
End If
WOWsht.Visible = False
InputSht.Select
Range("regime_list", Range("regime_list").End(xlDown)).Cells.ClearContents

'Part #1
Call get_predicted_data(thisfile, gage_tape_run, unique_gage_list, gage_factors, config_list)

'Part #2
Call get_corrected_test_data(thisfile, gage_tape_run, unique_gage_list, gage_factors, config_list, regime_sub_list)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub


'Part 2
Sub get_corrected_test_data(thisfile, gage_tape_run, unique_gage_list, gage_factors, config_list, regime_sub_list)

thisfile.Activate
InputSht.Select
Set regimerng = Range("regime_list", Range("regime_list").End(xlDown))
regime_list = regimerng.Value

reg_dir = Range("reg_dir")
If Right(reg_dir, 1) <> "\" Then
    reg_dir = reg_dir & "\"
End If
reg_f = Range("reg_f")

'Part 2 fails when trying to open the workbook
If AlreadyOpen(reg_f) Then
Else
    Workbooks.Open reg_dir & reg_f
End If
Set reg_wb = Workbooks(reg_f)
reg_wb.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' rest of the macro '   
End Sub
```

Comment: there are some subs/functions in there, that are called to, so would need to see the code for them.  Closing & disposing of objects used, is a great way, making sure you're not using variants/objects when you can define the classes properly, also erasing arrays etc.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2010 or earlier, saving the **workspace** can free up memory, not saving the workbook as far as I know. It cannot be used in Excel 2013+ because the workspace was abandoned.

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with your arrays than any objects you're holding references to, but it's impossible to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: Is it possible that the end of #1 is actually where the hangup is?  I.e., you toggle on `xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end, which maybe leaves the worksheet recalculating for a while before it can close?

Comment: How much more code needs to be seen? I added part of the sub for Part #2. The macro breaks down right at the beginning of Part #2 when I try to open the large Excel file. 


Also, how does close/dispose of objects as opposed to just erasing/emptying them?

Comment: Any chance you are using 32-bit excel? Variant arrays do tend to take up their fair share of memory but I personally have had no issue with storing millions of rows of data in a variant array on 64-bit. I recently tried to run a macro that stores only 70ish thousand rows of data on a colleagues computer (which uses 32-bit excel) and it immediately got OOM error.

Comment: Yea I'm using 32-bit Excel 2010. I don't see how the variant arrays in my specific situation can be the problem, though. I've cut out all the "fat" before running part #2. All the ones that are non-empty are required for Part #2. In my workaround of closing/re-opening the workbook, I'd have to create those same non-empty arrays again to run Part #2. I guess I can look into saving the workspace instead of just saving the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using an 800MB Excel file! That is an insane file size for a workbook, I'm surpised it even opens at all. If you have that much data you should move it MS Access and query the database. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849580/export-ms-access-tables-through-vba-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-same-directory) and [here](http://www.accessibledatasolutions.com/articles11/AccessexportExcel.htm) and [here](http://www.askeygeek.com/vba-code-to-export-access-data-to-excel/) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/import-access-query-result-into-excel-spreadsheet/4f4ba7ab-70d2-4d27-96dd-5adb1ec89a2c).

NB: you might also want to look into why your [Excel file is that big](http://www.wikihow.com/Reduce-Size-of-Excel-Files).

Comment: Well I didn't ask for it in Excel file, but that's how they gave it to me.

Comment: Do you know what the data source was e.g. a database? Do you have direct access to it? Can you get the data in a text file?

Comment: No this large Excel file was created by its own set of macros that imports data from text files into individual sheets. I think there are some macros that do additional calcs after import. So this large Excel file has over 70 worksheets and each sheet has a ton of data. I tried a simple import of the Excel file (xlsm) into Access, but it didn't work. Also there are more than 250 columns (fields) in each sheet. This exceeds an Access limitation that isn't present in Excel.

Comment: You'd have to normalize the data (http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/genaccess/databasenorm.html) which could take ages if the wb is that big. Could you create say 10 new workbooks to hold 7 sheets each?

Comment: So is the answer to my original question: there's no other way?

Comment: IMO it's not so much to do with the code as the size of the file but there are some things to try - remove the Call keyword and the parenthesis from your sub calls, declare gage_tape_run etc locally, not globally, check sort_rng_arr and other functions to see if any of the built in methods can be used instead e.g. remove_dupes_array - the built in remove duplicates might be more efficient. I'd still suggest if you dont need every sheet to be in one wb break them out to new wbs.