# Access 2016 VBA code to export to Excel, 'could not find installable ISAM'

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a database in Access with multiple tables. My end goal is to **create a form with a button, that when pressed, runs a macro. This macro will run custom VBA code.**

When run, I want the macro to **create a new Excel workbook with one worksheet, and import one specific table into that worksheet.**

Currently, this is my VBA code. I have literally 0 experience with VBA, so have no idea if this code will work or not. I found this code online as an answer to a question about a similar goal, and is not mine ([Export MS Access tables through VBA to an excel spreadsheet in same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849580/export-ms-access-tables-through-vba-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-same-directory))

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function exportToExcel()

Dim outputFileName As String
outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Export_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel2Xml, "all_data", outputFileName, True

End Function
```

I opened the VBA editor, created a new module called `export module` that is in the Modules folder in the navigator pane on the right side of the VBA editor window. The `Option Compare Database` bit was there already, and I typed the rest into this new module.

After saving the module, I created a new Macro, in which I have the `RunCode` command, and the Function field being `=exportToExcel()`. When I run the Macro, I get the error

```
Run-time error '3170':
Could not find installable ISAM.
```

Does anyone know where this error is coming from, and how I fix it? Also would you be able to comment on my VBA code and tell me if anything is wrong and what I should change, or if I'm even going about automating an export to Excel in the correct way?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did more digging an was able to find a solution if anybody finds this question in the future.

I don't know what the whole ISAM issue was, but [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbH5z1SunNM) was critical to completing my desired task. I created a new module in the VBA editor, and wrote this code inside.

```
Sub exportToXL()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim dbTable As String
Dim xlWorksheetPath As String

'<PATH> is the location you want the Excel file saved to, C:\ etc...
xlWorksheetPath = "<PATH>"

xlWorksheetPath = xlWorksheetPath & "xlExportAccessToExcel.xls"

'table1 is generic table name, this is the name of the table you want to export
dbTable = "table1"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, tablename:=dbTable, FileName:=xlWorksheetPath, hasfieldnames:=True

ErrorHandlerExit:

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & ";Description: " & Err.Description

    Resume ErrorHandlerExit


End Sub
```

I ran this module straight from inside the VBA editor, navigated to the file location i specified, and found a new Excel workbook with the desired data inside!

Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this was a reference to the wrong excel library and that changing the code from using

> acSpreadsheetTypeExcel2Xml

to

> acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9

has actually made the difference, based on whatever versionof excel is installed on the host machine.

Comment: I have Excel 2016 installed, with the new code in my answer above it worked with both ...Excel9 and with ...Excel12Xml